# Jquery Enter Key Follow Hyperlink

Tags: jquery

No jquery experience, just want to get this simple thing working.

I've got images that I can navigate by left/right key on the keyboard.  Click in the result frame and you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZT9P/1/

I just want to update the jquery such that pressing enter will trigger following the hyperlink for the active image.

HTML:

```
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
    display: inline-block;
}
.title.active {
    border: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var $title = $('.title')
var o = {
    37: 'prev',
    39: 'next'
}

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var dir = o[e.which];
    var $active = $('.active'),
        i = $title.index($active);
    if (!$active.length) {
        $title.first().addClass('active');
        return;
    } else {
        if (dir === 'next' || dir === 'prev') {
            $active.removeClass('active')[dir]().addClass('active');
        } 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var dir = o[e.which];
    var $active = $('.active'),
        i = $title.index($active);
    if (!$active.length) {
        $title.first().addClass('active');
        return;
    } else {
        if (dir === 'next' || dir === 'prev') {
            $active.removeClass('active')[dir]().addClass('active');
        } else if(e.keyCode == '13') {
            link = $('.active a').attr('href');
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    }
})
```

What I added is a check whether the pressed button is 'Enter' ( keyCode = 13), and if so get the link saved in the href Attribut of the a in the active div and open it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XZT9P/4/

// Edit:
I just minimized your code:

CSS:

```
.title {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url('http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png');
}
.title.active {
    border: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

JS:

```
var $title = $('.title')
var o = {
    37: 'prev',
    39: 'next'
}

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var dir = o[e.which];
    var $active = $('.active'),
        i = $title.index($active);
    if (!$active.length) {
        $title.first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        if (dir === 'next' || dir === 'prev') {
            $active.removeClass('active')[dir]().addClass('active');
        } else if(e.keyCode == '13') {
            window.location.href = $('.active').attr('dummy-link');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title" dummy-link="http://www.google.com"></div>
<div class="title" dummy-link="http://www.reddit.com"></div>
<div class="title" dummy-link="http://www.yahoo.com"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YzaFf/

Comment: btw: you could minimize your code, when your giving the div a background-image via CSS and a dummy-Atrribute with the link. This would eliminate the need of having additional < a >s and < img >s.

Comment: That minimized code looks great.  In reality each image will be different, but I can still use some of this.  Thanks a lot for your help!